# What does CFNetwork error -4 in domain CFStreamErrorHTTP mean?

Tags: cocoa, macos-carbon, cfnetwork

A customer is reporting a connection failure with a strange profile: it apparently only fails for the very first URL request via CFNetwork since the app has launched.

The error code apparently being returned by CFNetwork is domain CFStreamErrorHTTP, but with error code -4, which does not correspond to any publicly defined error code for this domain.

In CFHTTPStream.h, the publicly defined error codes for CFStreamErrorHTTP end auspiciously at -3, strongly hinting that -4 may be an error code that Apple is using but which has not yet been publicly documented.

Any idea what's going on here? Has anybody else seen this error code and found rhyme or reason for it?

Comment: how are they connecting to the internet?  if it's through CLEAR or 4G something or other maybe their modem drops the request while it's reconnecting?

Comment: Good thought, they are connecting through a regular cable ISP. I'm wondering if it has something to do with 3rd party software e.g. like Little Snitch. Checking with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the final answer and this may have changed since they closed sourced CFNetwork, but I did find the following online which indicates that -4 is a connection lost error.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-129.9/HTTP/CFHTTPConnection.c

Comment: Thanks! That's a good find, and corresponds in description to what the customer is seeing. Now if I can only figure out why connection would get lost on the first try...

Comment: Also pointed out by a friend, this older post on MacNetworkProg: http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2009/Mar/msg00007.html

Comment: Are they over some sort of VPN which was shut before the app starts? More generally, what conditions is the device/mac in when the app is started?

Comment: Reason I ask the latter is that perhaps the dhcp lease is dropped/expired which can cause "lost connections"

Comment: Nothing unusual that I can glean so far. What's most interesting to me is the circumstances are reproduced by quitting/relaunching the application. This is not consistent as far as I can imagine with a DHCP lease issue which would be more system-wide than app-lifetime-wide.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to show some of the code that's failing, but a few questions spring to mind. First, can you trace this issue yourself, can you reproduce it? In particular, it would be interesting to see on which thread this happens, and what's the current runLoop mode. It could be indicative of a stream or connection that fails scheduling on the internal CF runloops.

Other than this (and it's a shame CFNetwork is no longer publicly updated), it could be a zillion things, but you'll need to log as much information as you can if you can't directly debug the failure (hint hint -- https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger can help you remotely log the info from the client).

Finally, ask the question on Mac Dev Forums (or iOS Dev Forums if your code runs on iOS). Ping Quinn, He Knows It All. Once he can't publicly answer the question, open a DTS incident and send him the ticket #. He's the guy you want to look into your problem :-)

Comment: Also have the client try a different connection configuration with the same machine (i.e. from a public Wifi hotspot, or at a different location). If it works, then you can circumvent the issue to this particular network configuration. Also if you're using SSL, make sure that your code is signed.